# Issue with a UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController inside another UINavigationController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

Don't ask me to show the code because there's no code. Everything has been done in a storyboard.

My app starts with a main navigation controller which holds a login view controller as its root view controller. The login view controller has a button. When the button is pressed a tab bar controller is pushed. The tab bar controller has 4 items. Each item is a secondary navigation controller maintaining its own stack of view controllers. So basically the structure is: main `UINavigationController`-> login view controller -> `UITabBarController` -> secondary `UINavigationController` -> array of view controllers.

The problem is: when I do my way along the stack of secondary navigation controller's view controllers I would like to get back to a previous view controller by pressing `Back` button on the navigation bar. But it turns out that the navigation bar belongs not to the current navigation controller (the secondary one)! It belongs to the main navigation controller! So when I tap the `Back` button I pop to the very beginning of the app, to the login view controller because the main navigation controller pops the tab bar controller. I hope I described the issue clearly.

Of course I can do a workaround. If I hide the main navigation controller's navigation bar then I'm presented with the secondary navigation controller's navigation bar which is exactly what I need. But I feel like it is not a proper solution. I feel like there must be a right one. What do you think, guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using a `UINavigationController` to segue from your login to your main `UITabBarController`... personally, I prefer to have a different `rootViewController` of the main `UIWindow` as a login or presenting the login *modally* (without animation)... this makes more sense, since you don't expect a user to "navigate back" to the login screen, but rather use a logout and switch context completely.